# Python: Returning items common to two or more lists

Tags: python, list, intersection

I'm a beginner here, so please bear with me! I have a chunk of code:

```
def friendslike(network,user):
    friends=[]
    friendgames=[]
    friends+=get_connections(network,user)
    for user in friends:
        friendgames.append(get_games_liked(network,user))
    return friendgames
```

this returns:

```
[['Seahorse Adventures', 'Ninja Hamsters', 'Super Mushroom Man'], ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords'], ['City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma', 'Super Mushroom Man']]
```

What I want to do is return the names of games that appear in two or more of the lists. I'm not sure of how to approach the problem - whether splitting the lists, or some kind of intersect query.

As I said, I'm new to Python, and coding in general. Any pointers appreciated - even if it's just telling me what to research.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Indeed, an "intersect query" is what you want.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want any game liked by two or more friends, I suggest counting the number of appearances of each game, and then returning those that appear more than once. You can use `collections.Counter` to do the counting easily:

```
import collections

def friendslike(network,user):
    games = collections.Counter()
    for friend in get_connections(network, user):
        games.update(get_games_liked(network, friend))
    return [game for game, count in games.items() if count >= 2]
```

Comment: That's some crazy voodoo magic right there! I've never seen this 'import' thing before. I'll have to do some research... Thanks!

Comment: `import` statements are used to get access to other modules of code, in this case, the `collections` module from the standard library. One of Python's design goals is to be a "batteries included" language, so its standard library has lots of useful stuff in it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It is a dict-like structure that counts the things you give to it. It's like an automatic counting function for a `dict`.

```
import collections
friendgames = [['Seahorse Adventures', 'Ninja Hamsters', 'Super Mushroom  Man'],
        ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords'],
        ['City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma', 'Super Mushroom Man']]
c = collections.Counter(b for a in friendgames for b in a)
print [a for a,b in c.items() if b >= 2]
```

This prints the only entry with at least two occurences, which is:

```
['Super Mushroom Man']
```

Comment: Wow, I liked to use of `b for a in friendgames for b in a` here. It seems sophisticated. Would you mind explaining it to us?

Comment: @ozgurv It's just a list comprehension, albeit with two levels. The first one, `for a in friendgames` iterates over all elements in `friendgames` with `a` as a variable for the current one, and the second one, `for b in a`, iterates over all values of `a` (the iteration variable from the first loop). Basically, it's an expression to get all elements from the nested list. Teh functionality is that of two nested loops, just expressed in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your array using the number of occurences after merging all sublists. I hope this example will help you:

```
from itertools import chain
friendgames = [['Seahorse Adventures', 'Ninja Hamsters', 'Super Mushroom Man'],
        ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords'],
        ['City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma', 'Super Mushroom Man']]
g = list(chain.from_iterable(friendgames))
rez=set([x for x in g if g.count(x)>1]) # more than 1 occurrence
print(rez)
# {'Super Mushroom Man'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ***set***.

```
gameSet = set()
set([g for games in gamesList for g in games if g in gameSet or gameSet.add(g)])
```

The list comp will only record those games that return `True` with `if g in gameSet`; if they've been added to the set at least once they get added to the final list.

Answer (score 0):

yes, welcome! here are some options to try  :)

```
#intersect options
jim = ['Seahorse Adventures', 'Ninja Hamsters', 'Super Mushroom Man']
bob = ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords']
tom = ['City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma', 'Super Mushroom Man']

#meathod 1
for j in jim:
    if j in tom:
        print j

#meathod 2, with dictionary
gamers = {'jim':jim
            ,'bob':bob
            ,'tom':tom
            }
games = {}
for g in gamers.keys():
    for game in gamers[g]:
        if game not in games.keys():
            games[game] = [g]
        else:
            games[game].append(g)
for g in games.keys():
    if games[g][1:]:
        print g, games[g]
```

I find the dictionary would be useful if the information were stored somewhere, because it would be easier to append to in my opinion and has more information. also the iterative approach is somewhat computationally expensive if you start using big lists or have to perform this operation often. but as a start I hope it helps.